# Apache2: Cannot access Userdir - Forbidden

Tags: apache, ubuntu, http-status-code-403

I am trying to run Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 21.10. However, I cannot get userdir to work. I did everything I can possibly google, except reinstalling apache. I am normally a Windows person, so this is driving me nuts.

What I did:

- Enable userdir.conf
- Set Permission of the folder public_html into 777, and change ownership to www-data
- Add Require all granted to literally everywhere I can think of: `apache2.conf`, `userdir.conf`, and the config in `sites-available` to include

```
    <Directory /home/*/public_html >
     Require all granted
     AllowOverride All
     Options +Indexes 
   </Directory>
```

Yet, for some reason, all I have is `ERROR 403: Forbidden` when trying to go to `http://localhost/~myusername`
What could I possibly be missing?
Thank you.

Comment: What user is your apache server using? Did you check the apache error log for more details?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out it is "because search permissions are missing on a component of the path". So just "chmod -R 755" my entire home folder. Probably not that good of a solution, but still, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Check your home directory

```
$ ll -d /home/USER
drwx------. USER USER /home/USER
```

Then give it

```
$ chmod 711 /home/USER
drwx--x--x. USER USER /home/USER
```

If you still receive this error, make sure that *directories* are set with `chmod 755` but don't run it across all files and folder, just run:

```
find /home/USER -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

The `type -d` will result only directories, and change them to `755` ...

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/768976/204785

## Solution 1: (Risky - Refer [Solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/768976/204785))

Add the apache2 user (in my case `www-data`), to the logged in user group. This way `www-data` has access to everything user `/home/joe`.

`adduser www-data joe`

Also all files under `public_html` must have `rx` permissions for the group.

`chmod -R g+rw /home/joe/public_html`

## Solution 2:

Allow any `other` to search(`x`) `/home/joe`

`chmod o+x /home/joe`

Also all files under `public_html` must be accessible by `others` for `rx` permissions.

`chmod -R o+rw /home/joe/public_html`